# What is the parity of the determinant of the adjacency matrix of a graph with an odd number of vertices?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

> A graph $G$  has an odd  vertices  and $A$ is a  adjacency matrix of graph $G$ , how  show 
>   $$\det (A)\equiv 0\pmod 2.$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $n$ be the number of vertices of the (simple) graph. Then the adjacency matrix $A$ is a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix, with integer entries, and with zeros along the main diagonal.

Let $S$ be the matrix obtained from $A$ by replacing any element $a_{ij}$ with $i<j$ by $−a_{ij}$. Of course $\det(A)\equiv \det(S)\pmod{2}$. Moreover the $S$ is skew-symmetric, that is $S^t=-S$ and
therefore $$\det(S)=\det(S^t)=\det(-S)=(-1)^n\det (S)=-\det(S)\implies \det(S)=0.$$
Since $\det(A)$ and $\det(S)=0$ have the same parity, we may conclude that $\det(A)$ is even.

Comment: Why do you need $S$? Is not $A=-A$ in $F_2$, so $\det(A)=(-1)^n\det(A)$.

Comment: In which filed are you working? Now, more than I look I think this is wrong.

Comment: Yes, but is this correct? You got $2\det (S)=0$. How you deduce $\det (S)=0$?

Comment: Sorry, now I remember, this is the reason why I introduced $S$. $2\det(S)=0$ is not a congruence it is an equality!

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: Actualy it is not clear. From 2det(S) = 0 you can say det(S) = 0 if char of field you work in is not 2 else you cant

Comment: @greedoid I introduced $S$ in order to work in $\mathbb{Z}$. If $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $2a=0$ then $a=0$. So if $2\det(S) = 0$ then I can say the $\det(S) = 0$.

Comment: Yes, I would like to belive that is OK because your proof, if it actualy works, is very nice. I'm just uncomfatable with this transition between $Z$ and $Z_2$

Answer (score 2):

Eigenvalues of $A$ must be integer or irrational number.

- **Suppose all $\lambda_{i}$s are integer:** then one $\lambda_{i}$ must be even.
  because:   $\sum _{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i} = 0$ , $n \equiv 1 \pmod 2$.
- **Suppose at least one $\lambda_{i}$ is irrational ($\lambda_{1}$):**
  We know that sum of irrational numbers is irrational, and
  $\sum _{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i} = 0$. Then exists other irrational number ($\lambda_{2}$) : $k_{1}.|\lambda_{1}| = k_{2}.|\lambda_{2}|$  and  $k_{1}, k_{2}$ is integer and $\lambda_{1}. \lambda_{2} \lt 0$.

  If $k_{1} \equiv k_{2} \pmod 2$ then exist one even integer number ($\lambda_{3}$).
  else suppose $k_{1} \equiv 0\pmod 2$ then $\lambda_{2} ^ {2} \equiv 0 \pmod 2$.

  We know $\lambda_{i} ^{2}$ must be integer ($\sum _{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i} ^{2} = 2m$). If $k_{2} > 1$ then $\lambda_{2} ^{2} $ is in $det A$ and problem solved.
  If  $k_{2} = 1$  then $k_{1} ^ {2}.|\lambda_{1}|^{2} = |\lambda_{2}|^ 2$ and it means $k_{1} | \lambda_{2}$ but $\lambda_{2}$ is irrational, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $m$ is the number of edges then we have

- $$ \sum _{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i} ^{2}  = 2 m$$
- $$ \det(A) = \prod _{i=1}^{n} \lambda _{i} $$
  suppose all of the $\lambda_{i} $ is odd then contradiction 1  then there exist  a $\lambda_{k}$ that even so $$ \det (A) \equiv 0 \pmod 2 $$

Comment: This proof is not correct. You are assuming that any eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ is an integer number!! This is false in general!